# How do I flag and categorize Drupal Commerce related products?

Tags: views, commerce

Given that there isn't a related products contrib module yet.

What is the canonical means (with priority of maintainability, developer experience) to flag related products and thus have them displayed in views ?

Would it include setting up content types with many different taxonomy vocabulary fields? Another product reference field?

Answer (score 1):

The core taxonomy module offers a flexible system for sorting content. You can easily build views based on content type and taxonomy.

Comment: I think Taxonomy on the product display nodes is the most common approach. Ryan did a video about that approach at http://vimeo.com/22748684

Comment: How would you then distinguish a related product relationship? Could you provide an example?